# Windows, MinGW и lib/a

Tags: c, windows, winapi, lib

Подскажите, чем отличаются файлы **lib** от файлов **a**?

Например, я разрабатываю под **Windows** с использованием **MinGW**, при использовании некоторых вещей требуются библиотеки.

Например, при использовании сокетов, мне приходилось искать и подключать к проекту файл **WS2_32.lib**, этих файлов у меня в системе несколько десятков, но все они находятся не в директории с компилятором. И у всех разный размер. Пришлось методом *тыка* определять, какой файл мне нужен, кидая его в папку с проектом...

Так же, например, при использовании **GetOpenFileName()** мне необходимо подключить какую-то библиотеку, чтобы решить проблему с неразрешенным внешним символом. Кто-то советует подключать **Comdlg32.lib**, кто-то **libcomdlg32.a**, а так же есть рекомендации использовать опцию линкера **lcomdlg32**.

Я совершенно запутался, особенно учитывая тот факт, что этих файлов у меня в системе множество, и все они разные...

Вопросы:

1) Чем отличается .lib от .a?

2) В **MinGW** при работе с **WinAPI** нужны .lib или .a?

3) Почему вообще при работе с **WinAPI** нужно что-то отдельно подключать/линковать, я думал достаточно одних заголовочных файлов, в которых объявлены соответствующие вещи...

Comment: зачем вам вообще MinGW для WinAPI?

Comment: Затем, что MS забросили компилятор **C** где-то на уровне неполной поддержки **C89**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Заголовочных файлов для использования DLL, естественно, недостаточно. Они содержат объявления функций, но как компоновщик найдет реализацию (точнее поймет, что она подгружается динамически)? Для этого к каждой DLL и прилагается статическая библиотека ("библиотека импорта"), которая предоставляет компоновщику необходимую информацию. *Технически библиотека импорта не является полноценной статической библиотекой (т.е., архивом объектных файлов), ее структура намного проще, но с точки зрения работы компоновщика особой разницы нет, поэтому можно назвать ее так.*

**lib** - расширение файлов статических библиотек, принятое в Windows. **a** - аналогично в UNIX-системах. MinGW на самом деле поддерживает оба формата библиотек (Источник: [Specify the libraries for the linker to use](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Specify_the_libraries_for_the_linker_to_use)). Если для вас это не работает, возможно, нужно просто обновить версию.

---

А искать библиотеки импорта методом тыка не надо. Открываете страницу документации для функции (например, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/commdlg/nf-commdlg-getopenfilenamew), у нее внизу указано имя библиотеки импорта (в данном случае Comdlg32.lib). Если ищете в папках mingw, добавляете в начало имени "lib..." и меняете расширение на ".а". Если в папках MinGW ее нет, скачиваете последнюю версию Windows SDK, устанавливаете и берете lib-файл из папки `Program Files\Microsoft SDKs` или `Program Files\Windows Kits`. С высокой вероятностью MinGW примет его.

Comment: Есть ещё одна полезная ссылка: [Interoperability of Libraries Created by Different Compiler Brands](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Interoperability_of_Libraries_Created_by_Different_Compiler_Brands), где объясняется, почему нельзя линковать библиотеки, собранные разными tool-chain.

Comment: Про несовместимость библиотек даже между версиями одного компилятора я знаю, поэтому мне и кажется странным, что в папке с компилятором **MinGW** нет .lib файлов для работы с сокетами или для работы с функцией GetOpenFileName(). Приходится эти файлы искать по всей системе, подбирая методом тыка, какой же файл подойдет моему компилятору.

Comment: @Максим В папке с MinGW есть все необходимые `.a` файлы для работы с WinAPI и ничего искать не надо. Для сокетов это `libws2_32.a`, а для указанной функции - `libcomdlg32.a`. Все они находятся в папке *mingw32\i686-w64-mingw32\lib*.

Comment: А в чем будет разница, и будет ли она вообще, если вместо параметра линкера для подключения файла .a я воспользуюсь просто копированием .lib файла в каталог с проектом? Я так делал, потому что однажды было некогда разбираться, а потом просто привык... Стыд)

Comment: @Максим Несовместимость на уровне бинарников более характерна для С++, а не для С. А искать методом тыка ничего не надо, открываете страницу документации для функции (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/commdlg/nf-commdlg-getopenfilenamew), у нее внизу указано имя библиотеки импорта (Comdlg32.lib). Если ищете в папках mingw, добавляете "lib..." и меняете расширение на .а. Если в папках Mingw ее нет, скачиваете последнюю версию Windows SDK, устанавливаете и берете lib-файл из папки `Program Files \ Microsoft SDKs` или Windows Kits.

Comment: "А в чем будет разница..." - Если это работает, то ни в чем. Но некоторые библиотеки используются очень часто, копировать их в каждый проект - бессмысленное забивание места на диске, лучше подключать по нормальному через настройки проекта.

Answer (score 3):

1. Статические файлы библиотек на Linux `.a`, а под Windows - `.lib`.
2. MinGW даже расшифровывается как Minimalist GNU for Windows, т.е. в некотором смысле предоставляет запуск некоторого окружения Linux на Windows.
3. Не могу ответить на этот вопрос, он скорее риторический, так как по моему мнению это просто составляющая часть работы программиста